# Numpy: Adding radius of circle to form diameter

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list that contains all the radii of a circle and I'm trying to compute the diameter of the circle with the diagonal radii.

My example function is as below:

```
radii=[2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.0, 2.2, 2.5, 2.1]

def dia(radius):
    Diameter = []
    for i in range(int(len(radii)/2)):
        print i
        Diameter.append(radii[i]+radii[int(len(radii)/2+i)])
    print Diameter

dia(radii)
```

Now this works for relatively small data set. But whenever I have a circle with lets say 100 radii and i have about ~100k circles. This function becomes really slow and it takes too long to run for all of them. I am wondering how can I speed this up with numpy or any python tools. Any one has idea ?

Comment: Are you using `radii` and `diameter` with their traditional definitions?

Comment: yes :) diameter is just 2*radii but in this case will be the diagonal radii.

Comment: What is a `diagonal radii`?

Comment: sorry maybe i wasn't clear. Imagine you have a circle but a not-so perfect circle. The diameter of will be 2 * radii (opposite to each other). Do you get what I mean ?

Comment: A not-so perfect circle could also be known as "not a circle". I think I get what you are saying though. You want the width of the shape for different angles though it. Is it safe to assume that the radii are equally spaced around the circumference?

Comment: yes you are technically right. It's not a circle but a circle-like shape. So yes the radii are equally spaced around the circumference. And yes basically how can I improve the speed of the above code :)

Comment: What do you want to do with the result of `dia(radii)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in NumPy you can simply do it like:

```
>>> radii = np.array([2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.0, 2.2, 2.5, 2.1])
>>> radii[:len(radii)/2] + radii[len(radii)/2:]
array([ 4.1,  4.6,  4.8,  4.3])
```

This is quite faster than a list comprehension based Python version of your code.

```
>>> radii = [2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.0, 2.2, 2.5, 2.1]*10**6
>>> radii_a = np.array(radii)
>>> %timeit [radii[i]+radii[int(len(radii)/2+i)] for i in xrange(int(len(radii)/2))]
1 loops, best of 3: 806 ms per loop
>>> %timeit radii_a[:len(radii)/2] + radii_a[len(radii)/2:]
100 loops, best of 3: 11.2 ms per loop
```

Note that the Python code is too slow because of so many global lookups happening each time for `len()`, `int()`(yes we can remove the `int()` call in Python 2) etc:

```
>>> %timeit le = int(len(radii)/2); [radii[i]+radii[le+i] for i in xrange(le)]
1 loops, best of 3: 300 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks python gurus, these are the answers that I needed. Numpy is awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

This is quite straight forward with numpy:

```
radii=np.array([2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.0, 2.2, 2.5, 2.1])
diameters = radii[:radii.size/2] + radii[radii.size/2:]
```

Comment: Thanks ebarr ! This is really straightforward and makes me look dumb !

Answer (score 1):

First, as [Ashwini Chaudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117537/908494) and [ebarr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117540/908494) both explain, you can convert the inner loop over 100 radii from a Python loop to a NumPy loop:

```
radii = np.array([2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.0, 2.2, 2.5, 2.1])
radii[:len(radii)/2] + radii[len(radii)/2:]
```

But you may want to consider also changing the outer loop to a NumPy loop, by using a 2D array instead of a list of arrays:

```
circles = np.array([[2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.0, 2.2, 2.5, 2.1],
                    [2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.0, 2.2, 2.5, 2.1]])
circles[:,:circles.shape[1]/2] + circles[:,circles.shape[1]/2:]
```

Comparing the times for 100k random circles of 100 radii, I get about a 11.3x speedup from just replacing the inner loop, a 36.8x speedup from replacing both. So, it's not as *much* of a benefit, but it's still definitely worth doing… assuming you can hold all your circles in memory at once, of course.

That last sentence may seem dismissive of the possibility (and your comment implies that you took it that way), but work out how much memory we're talking about here. You have ~100k circles, each with 100 radii, so that's about 10m radii. Each of which is a `float64`, which takes 8 bytes. Plus another 100 bytes or so for the array header. Meaning we're talking under 80MB. That's *nothing*. Unless you're expecting to deal with at least an order of magnitude more data in the future, the speed and convenience benefits of putting everything in a 2D array are almost certainly a win.

Comment: Thank you abarnert, I realize memory in this case is the problem :)

Comment: @Arbitel: Is memory *really* a problem? We're talking under 80MB here.

Comment: I made a silly mistake while modifying the code, i was looping the lists while doing that and it froze. My bad.

Is there a way to to Array comprehension ? I only want to sum the radii which has a value of >0. Some of them has negative values. Can i do something like [radii[:len(radii)/2] + radii[len(radii)/2:] if radii[x] > 0 ] ?

Comment: Okay I found a way of doing it by doing this radii[radii<0] = np.nan.

Comment: @Arbitel: You _can_ simulate an array comprehension by using a generator expression and `np.fromiter` (or a list comprehension and `np.array`, if you have memory to waste), but it's rarely a good idea, because then you're just back to doing the loops in slow Python instead of fast NumPy. The way you found is exactly the right answer.

Comment: Thank you abarnert ! :) Everything is working great now. I'm loving python , numpy and this community.